# Creating a file with current date and time in C++

Tags: c++

**I have written this code to make a file with current date. It is working 100 percent fine but is this approach right? or is this solution optimum? Can anyone help me to come up with better solution if required?**

What I have done here in this code.

1. Firstly I wrote date in a file named **name.txt**.
2. Then I read that file using **getline** function and stored in string variable **s**.(I used getline to make date in a single string)
3. Then I removed **name.txt**, because now it is useless.
4. Now I made a new file using c_style string **s.c_str()** and wrote something in file.( Note: **s** is a string variable containing date. )
5. Finally, I opened that file using  **s.c_str()** to read the data in file.

```
#include <ctime> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 
//SHAKAS ULTIMATE CODE   
int main() 
{ 
    string s;
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);

    ofstream file;
    file.open("name.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
    file<< ltm->tm_mday<<"-";
    file<<1 + ltm->tm_mon<<"-";
    file<<1900 + ltm->tm_year;
    //file<<1 + ltm->tm_hour<<"_";  Uncomment it if you want hours/min/sec on the name of file 
    //file<<1 + ltm->tm_min<<"_";
    //file<<1 + ltm->tm_sec;
    }
    else
    cout<<"Unable to create file";

    file.close();

ifstream i;
i.open("name.txt");
    while(!i.eof())
        {           
        getline(i, s);
        }
        i.close();


remove("name.txt");

ofstream fileC;
fileC.open(s.c_str());                   //writing in file, just to check 
fileC << "WHO IS THE BOSS...?";
fileC.close();


string a;
i.open(s.c_str());
    while(!i.eof())
        {           
        getline(i, a);        //Opening that file again to check if its written
        cout<<a;
        }
        i.close();




}
```

Comment: Why do you need to write the date and time to a file, only to read it back in, immediately?

Comment: Yeah,to read it back using **getline** function to store it in a single string in a string variable.

Comment: Well, why don't you just store it in the same single string variable in the first place? Open your C++ textbook to the chapter that explains how to use `std::ostringstream`, and see some examples of doing just that. As an extra bonus, all the code that's currently writing to the file remains identical, and will just write to the `std::ostringstream`, and you get rid of all the code that reads from the file and deletes it, which is just a waste of time.

Comment: Please explain a little bit about how to use `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will go through that chapter.